# Android studio kotlin viewBinding caching problems class name

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-viewbinding

I renamed a class, then gradled the ability to enable viewBinding.

When I import the class, it doesn't find the renamed class, but the one with the old class name.

Can you give me a hand?

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

Comment: Tbh I think doin' the ol' reliable: clean and rebuild -> invalidate caches would fix the issue

Comment: Have you tried clean project and rebuild it ?

Comment: Invalidate Cache should fix this. If not can you share the class name old & new

Comment: I tried to do: Clean project -> Build project -> Invalidate caches, in this sequence, the problem is not solved.

Comment: The old class name was: `ConfigurableWidgetConfigureActivity`
The new class name is: `MyWidgetConfigureActivity`

When I import it finds this: `import com.myapp.test.databinding.ConfigurableWidgetBinding`

Comment: I tried to search if there was any reference to the old name but I can't find anything.

Comment: wait a minute ! FYI , binding class are not generated from class name . Binding class are generated from your layout file name so if you change layout file name then it will have effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding class name are decided from your layout file name not your class name so doesn't matter what is or what was your activity or fragment name . It will always use layout file name . Let's say i have created `result_profile.xml` file then binding class name will be `ResultProfileBinding` now it doesn't matter whatever class i create or rename

For more information , checkout this link
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding